# Multiple instances of playing a video on one page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, vimeo

I have some code that shows a cover image over a video, upon clicking said image it auto plays the video. Currently this code works for one video on one page (because it uses ID's).

The code is leaning on [Froogaloop](https://gist.github.com/jyr/1420508) to control and play Vimeo.

Using jQuery how can I convert the following code so that it will work with  more than 1 video on a page (currently it breaks):

```
// Control Vimeo videos
var iframe = document.getElementById('video');

// $f == Froogaloop
var player = $f(iframe);

var playButton = document.getElementById("play-me");

playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  player.api("play");
    $('.bg-image').addClass('hide-me');

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.bg-image').css('z-index','-1');
    }, 1000);
});
```

**This is my HTML:**

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
    <div class="bg-image" id="play-me">
       <span class="play">
         <i class="i-play"></i>
       </span>
    </div>
    <iframe src="" id="video"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Use class or add random number after video id

Comment: @ColinCline How would I do that?

Comment: This page or `.video-wrapper` may contain multiple videos? sry i asking too much in comment because this community are rdy to give downvote instead answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conver ids to classes:

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
    <div class="bg-image" class="play-me">
       <span class="play">
         <i class="i-play"></i>
       </span>
    </div>
    <iframe src="" class="video"></iframe>
</div>
```

and modify your js/jquery to this:

```
var playButton = $(".play-me");

playButton.get(0).addEventListener("click", function() {
    var iframe = $(this).next('.video').get(0),// or use closest() based on your condition
    player = $f(iframe);
    player.api("play");
    $(this).addClass('hide-me');

    setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).css('z-index','-1');
    }, 1000);
});
```

**IF**
you had to add more videos inside the same `.video-wrapper`, use `.closest()` as i commented in top otherwise `.next()` will works fine.

**Explanation**:
With using `$(this)` make us confident that code will do changes just on that element we clicked not all.

Comment: For some reason when I copy your code I get an console error saying that this line isn't a function: 'playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {'

Comment: @egr103 You changed `id="play-me"` to `class="play-me"` in HTML?

Comment: @egr103 good call. I was trying to bind a jquery object with plain js handler. Fixed now.

Comment: Ok after noticing your updated code I copy/pasted, which gives me the error in console when I click the .play-me class. The error reads: "Uncaught TypeError: this.element.getAttribute is not a function"

It refers to froogaloop, which is what I'm using to control Vimeo (you have to), specifically this line: // Register message event listeners
                playerDomain = getDomainFromUrl(this.element.getAttribute('src'));

Comment: @egr103 You don't have any function `getAttribute()` in your js file in above. could you see what line your console shows as error and check if that line is part of my code or not (and paste what line)?

Comment: Its referring to Froogaloop, which is what I'm using to control the Vimeo video, which must mean something is missing from your code. The error relates to line 26 of its code https://gist.github.com/jyr/1420508

Comment: @egr103 edited. Again combination of js and Jquery. Its not big deal but i wasn't aware Froogaloop will use js element not jQuery object.

Comment: Ok so, this now stops other videos from playing, which is great. However, the code doesn't specifically target the cover images. When you click .play-me it hides the cover images for all videos on the page, not just the one I clicked. The code should only hide the image image i've just clicked

Comment: @egr103 its easy. I forgot that because your main problem was something else. edited. If this answer was helpful set it as an answer. regards

Comment: Sorry its still doing the same thing, sorry for all the comments

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there will be multiple `play-me` elements on the page, assign them each a class instead of an ID. Then just add a click handler with your existing code inside, making sure to use `this` to ensure the method calls are called on the element that's clicked.

Since you're setting the `z-index` in your timeout you may just want to put everything else there too.

```
$('.play-me').on('click', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);

  setTimeout(function() {
    player.api('play');

    $this
      .css('z-index', '-1')
      .addClass('hide-me');
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I get player is not defined in the console when using your code.

Comment: I get the error after changing my class names for both .play-me and .video

Comment: Being that nothing in my code references `player` that it may be the player api complaining about something. Does their documentation state something has to be written a certain way for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

How is the video set on place? Is hardcoded through html? I cant comment, this should be a comment... Btw, why the mix with jquery and plain javascript?

Comment: Some times for boosting speed and lack of knowledge from programmer, he/she had to use both (its not bad thing)

Comment: Nope not a bad thing, just curiousity from my side:)